# Google Tag Manager hangs on XHR Ready State Changed

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, reactjs, google-tag-manager, webpack

Alright this is a strange one. I've added the Google tag manager script to the bottom of my page and I've published the container but I've removed all the tags (just in case one of the tags was the culprit). My code snippet looks like this:

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5T8FJJ"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5T8FJJ');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

What appears to be happening is that something in the tag assistant code is hanging and causing the page to become unresponsive for several seconds.

You can see here in this screenshot that it looks like `onreadystatechange` is taking almost 3200ms.

[image]

[image]

For a little more context, I am doing server-side rendering with node/react/webpack. Here is my page template that I'm rendering on the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="csrf" content=<%= csrf %> />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= styleUrl %>" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.data = <%= data %>;
    </script>

    <div id="react-target">
    <%= html %>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= commonsUrl %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= scriptUrl %>"></script>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5T8FJJ"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5T8FJJ');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my first attempt at using google tag manager so I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my configuration or not. Appreciate the help.

**UPDATE**

I have common webpack bundle called `common.js`. According to the network tab it appears that the google tag manager script forces it to be downloaded a 2nd time. Really strange.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you remove the tag assist extension? Does it still hang?

Comment: No it doesn't. It also doesn't hang if I remove the webpack scripts. So something weird is happening when the two are used together. I'm selectively removing each library to see if I can track it down.

Comment: @Blexy I just posted an update. It appears tag manager forces another download of my common.js bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out the issue. I had a partial that was loading a google adwords conversion tracking code:

```
<!-- Google Code for Registration Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  var google_conversion_id = xxx;
  var google_conversion_language = "en";
  var google_conversion_format = "3";
  var google_conversion_color = "xxx";
  var google_conversion_label = "xxx";
  var google_remarketing_only = false;
  /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
<noscript>
  <div style="display:inline;">
  <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxx/?label=rX1nCMeesFkQ29ac1wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

This was being compiled and loaded by webpack which was causing some weird race condition or contention of some kind. Still not sure why this would be a problem but it fixed it.